# Javascript - print pdf in iframe with workaround for Firefox bug

Tags: javascript, firefox, pdf, iframe

I am using this bit of javascript to print a pdf file that is displayed in an iframe.

```
function printPage()
{
  var div = document.getElementById("printerDiv");
  div.innerHTML = '<iframe src="/cgi-bin/pr.pl?tx.pdf"   onload="this.contentWindow.focus();this.contentWindow.print();"></iframe>';
}
```

Works perfectly in Chrome, but in Firefox I get the following error due to a [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=911444) that has been around for over a year

Error: Permission denied to access property "print"

Can anyone offer a workaround that will let me print a PDF document in Firefox without displaying it?  Obviously, I am using an iframe (out of sight) for this now, but that appears to be the problem.  There is no possibility of using Chrome, unfortunately.

---

**